# Stuck on proof of Lemma 6.2.2 (Oksendal, SDEs)

Tags: stochastic-processes, proof-explanation, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

First, here is the proof out of the book.  I will explain what is causing confusion below the image but I will point out that my question is in regards to the highlighted statement.

[image]

Now, the reason I am stuck has to do with the projection $\mathcal P_\mathcal L$.  Oksendal does not seem to explicitly state the projection is orthogonal.  If it were, I would have no problem with the highlighted statement.

My question is how to justify the highlighted statement.  Does the projection $\mathcal P_\mathcal L$ have to be orthogonal for this to hold?

Comment: For  $X\in L^2$ and a $\sigma$-subalgebra $\mathcal G$, the conditional expectation $\mathbb E[X|\mathcal G]$ is the orthogonal projection of $X$ on the subspace of $\mathcal G$-measurable functions.

Comment: @Mick I agree with you on this but he does not seem to assume $\mathcal P_\mathcal L(X)=E[X|\mathcal G]$ but rather proves it after the statement I am stuck on.  Are you suggesting that $\mathcal P_\mathcal L$ is implicitly assumed to be orthogonal?

Comment: Well, since we are in $L^2$ I would assume "any" sensible projection to be orthogonal. How does Oksendal define $\mathcal P_\mathcal L$?

Comment: @Mick All he says is: Let $\mathcal P_\mathcal L$ denotes the projection from $L^2(P)$ into $\mathcal L(Z,t)$. He also defines, $\mathcal L(Z,t)=$ the closure in $L^2(P)$ of all linear combinations $c_0+c_1Z_{t_1}+\dots+c_k Z_{t_k};$ $0\leq t_i\leq t$, $c_j\in\Bbb R$.

Comment: Oh, I see, then it's 99% sure that he assumes $\mathcal P_{\mathcal L}$ is an orthogonal projection. He defines $\widetilde X := X- \mathcal P_{\mathcal L}X$ and then claims that $\widetilde X$ is independent of $\mathcal G$, shows this by showing that the covariances with $Z_{s_k}$'s are 0 and uses underlying normality. Pretty sure its orthogonal.

Comment: @Mick Ok.  Thank you.